# How to prove that given a line L prove that all points of a fixed distance k form two lines parallel to L

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

How can I prove start this?I know intuitively since they never meet they are parallel, but I don't think that is a direct proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a rotation and then a translation to your line so that it is the axis $y=0$. Then, the distance from a point $(x,y)$ to the line is equal to $\lvert y\rvert$. Hence the points with distance $k$ are the lines $y=\pm k$.

Comment: Right a translation is perfect! translation map parallel lines to parallel lines, how could I forget. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.